# How to Achieve model binding for Complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My model is :

```
public class ContactInfo
        {

            public IEnumerable<SupplierContact> PriceRequest { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SupplierContact> OrderConfirmation { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SupplierContact> Account { get; set; }
        }




 public class SupplierContact
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    }
```

and my Controller action is

```
public ActionResult EditContactInfo(ContactInfo contactInfo)
{
// not getting any values here..
}
```

View is rendering like :

```
 @foreach (SupplierContact PriceRequest in Model.PriceRequest)
                {
                <tr class="">
                    <td style="text-align: left;" class="csstd-left">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => PriceRequest.Email)</td>
                    <td class="csstd">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => PriceRequest.MobilePhone)</td>
                    <td class="csstd">@PriceRequest.Title</td>
                    <td class="csstd">@PriceRequest.FirstName</td>
                    <td class="csstd">@PriceRequest.LastName</td>                  

                </tr>
                }
```

And I am referencing `@model ContactInfo` in my view

However i can achieve it using

```
Request.Form.Get("PriceRequest.Email")
```

but I want to use model binding feature .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop (and you will need to change the collections from `IEnumerable` to `IList` to the `name` attributes are correctly indexed

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PriceRequest.Count; i++) {
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.PriceRequest[0].Email)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.PriceRequest[i].MobilePhone)
}
```

Alternatively you can create a `EditorTemplate` for `SupplierContact` and use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PriceRequest)
```

This will generate html like

```
<input name="PriceRequest[0].Email" ...
<input name="PriceRequest[0].MobilePhone" ...
<input name="PriceRequest[1].Email" ...
<input name="PriceRequest[2].MobilePhone" ...
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks . I was missing the way MVC render the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at display and editor templates. Than you can create a view called `SupplierContact`. MVC automatically knows what to show if he see the complex type.

See this example:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-2

So create a folder: DisplayTemplates in your views folder.
Then create a partial view called SupplierContact. 
Set the model of the partial view as a SupplierContact.
Create the labels for displaying and run your application again.

For editing, create a EditorTemplates folder.

Comment: Lengthy process? This is done in 2 minutes. This is the way it should be done in MVC. In this way every view is the same when you display or edit an object of that type.